# Bash is putting out an "invalid char ' ' in expression" in my awk section

Tags: bash, vim, awk

I am currently writing a small game in gawk and i am using a Raspberry Pi with gawk installed.
After saving my code on a windows editor to move the file to my raspberry, i encountered some problems with the encoding (had to remove some pesky ^M chars). The file is saved in UTF-8 ('locale' tells me the LANG=en_GB.UTF-8). :set encoding? in vim is telling me im using UTF-8 too (same goes for :set fileencoding? ).

When i try to execute my code, which is saved as a .sh script, the interpreter stops at the first OR sign "|"

```
while ((FieldSize !~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/) || (FieldSize < 4))
```

The error message is: invalid char 'squarishlooking char' in expression.

I have tried several fixes, i also viewed the file in the hexview and both |-chars are correctly identified as '7C', the hexvalue of | in the ascii-chart.

The error only happens when i use the combination <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd> to input the character into vim. The error wont happen if i enter the INSERT-mode of vim and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> 124 (which is the dez-value of | in the ascii chart). If i view either of the 2 options in a hexview, the chars are correctly nested between a space-char (hex: 20) on either side --> 20 7c 7c 20.

I am now also highlighting nonascii-chars in my vim with

```
syntax match nonascii "[^\x00-\x7F]"
highlight nonascii guibg=Red ctermbg=2
```

and the pipe-char only gets highlighted when i use <kbd>altGr</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>.

Always using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> xxx isnt really a desriable solution in my humble opinion.
I want my script to work when i use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd> for putting in a "|". Is there any soltution to this apart from the workaround with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>124</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`squarishlooking char` means it isn't a normal pipe. It is something your terminal doesn't have a character for. If you can't see that with `xxd` then you likely aren't looking at the right file/place.

Comment: With about 8 bytes per row in hexview , the right mark would be hard to miss imo. Looking at the wrong place is highly improbable, since i only have this one shellscript in my folder. The hexvalue of the square displayed must be e296a0 --> ■ .

Comment: @Mustermann What keyboard layout are you using? Is this Windows, linux, or OS X? What does `echo '<AltGr-7>' | hexdump -C` output?

Comment: If i type your code verbatim it outputs <AltGr-7> | hexdump -C, i doubt thats what you want. I I type echo '<|>' | hexdump -C, the output is <|> | hexdump -C... weird thing

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean literally I meant if you hit `<AltGr-7>` in that position. So `echo '|' | hexdump -C`. Where the pipe there is from pressing `<AltGr-7>`. You can't use `<AltGr-7>` for the pipe before `hexdump`. The shell doesn't understand whatever magical pipe-like character that is either. =) But that shows my point, `<AltGr-7>` is *not* producing an ASCII pipe character. It is producing something else.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried finding out the keyboard layout with setxbmap -query, but there seemed to be an issue with xkb not being able to open some display file. Feels like i could actually save time by feeding the bits one by one into the usb-plug myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a shell script, but an awk script. You see the shell complaining that it does not understand what to do with two pipes right after each other. This would be the standalone version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
# your code here
```

Then, your OS will figure out automatically from the HashBang (`#!`) to run `gawk` with it.

Alternatively, this would also work, by running first a new shell, which calls an awk command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
awk 'your awk code here'
```

Comment: The code is in fact a shellscript, i only put in a small snippet since the thing is getting a bit long. It starts with #!/bin/ bash and then continues to call awk -v randomnr=$RANDOM ' code here {} - ' ... I never had problems with the code not working until i started to transfer the file via windows editor.